# Formating timestamp correctly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, wfs-t, timestamp, formatting

I am trying to automatically update timestamp of a feature from WFS-T connection in QGIS 3.16.

According to the DescribeFeatureType, the attribute is defined as following:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="DATE" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
```

Timestamp is used by an external progman, that accepts timestamp in following format:

```
2021-08-01T12:32:51Z
```

I would like to save the timestamp in the format above. I have configured the field in QGIS 3.16 with following parameters, which seem to give the correct format in preview:

[image: Field configuration]

However, examining the sent POST request I noticed that the format of the timestamp has changed into following:

```
2021-08-25T10:02:42.406Z
```

How can I get QGIS to format the timestamp correctly without the decimals after seconds?

Comment: How are you sending the POST data to the server?

Comment: Layer is added through WFS-T service, so QGIS creates and sends the POST data.

Answer (score 1):

On QGIS 3.20 Odense the same settings seem to work as expected:

[image]

Also, in QGIS tables you can define virtual fields, which get calulcated at runtime, therefore also before exporting:

`Attribute Table` (`F6`) -> click on the `Open Field Calculator` icon (the abacus), then:

[image]

Comment: I tested this  with QGIS 3.20- preview looks as it is supposed to, but the POST request QGIS sends has the decimals after seconds.